# Android app, copy to clipboard clipping text thats off web page to the right

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, copy-paste

I have developed an app that contains html document assets for smartphones (480dps wide). These contain long textual links I want the user to copy for exercises (and paste into the app). I've noticed that text which is not visible on the web page AND is not wrapping is being ignored when the user tries to copy a block. To test this I made this piece of text

```
GRAB START<BR>
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z<BR>
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z<BR>
A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.M.N.O.P.Q.R.S.T.U.V.W.X.Y.Z<BR>
A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.M.N.O.P.Q.R.S.T.U.V.W.X.Y.Z<BR>
GRAB END<BR>
```

(cant show image cos I'm new to this site)
The first two lines wrap. The last two lines do not wrap and only A to W is visible in the webview. When the user uses a long click and moves the copy marker from GRAB START to GRAB END I get the following in the clip buffer (sent to eclipse log console):

01-17 11:47:06.963: D/clipBoard(6470): GRAB START A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.M.N.O.P.Q.R.S.T.U.V.W A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I.J.K.L.M.N.O.P.Q.R.S.T.U.V.W GRAB END

".X.Y.Z" is dropped from the last two lines. This is contrary to all expectations. I can't reformat/retype all the asset html files to see which lines need spaces or newlines just to make the long chucks wrap and become visible.

I am using a basic webview intent. I have vertical scrolling but not horizontal scrolling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have these two metatags in the html files

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Any Work around, fix, something I should be doing??